# Cloudflare doesn't respect my origin cache control header

Tags: cloudflare

My nginx server return

> cache-control: public, max-age=14400, s-maxage=2592000

for every request.
But for html files, it still returns

> cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC

for other cachable file extensions, it returns:

> cf-cache-status: EXPIRED

I've already purge all cache and refresh my browser for several times.
Something wrong with my settings?

Answer (score -1):

Check cloudfalre cache level settings.